# Are there any non-static (ESD safe) materials to print with?

Tags: electronics, print-material

I am attempting to replace an SFX power supply of my computer with a PicoPSU. I would like to manufacture a plate to fill the vacant place and to pass through the power lead, and maybe host a power switch and a 60 mm fan.

The thing is, I need to have a material that is ESD safe, i.e. does not collect static electricity. Meaning that the conductivity should be somewhere between 10^(-4)and 10^(-9) if plastic. And also a material that can take screws. So, a metal or some kind of conductive plastic.

Question is, are there any known ones?

If I will seek out to buy or borrow a 3D printer, I need it to support this choice of material.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes there are ESD Compatible filament materials.  One manufacturer is [3dxtech](https://www.3dxtech.com/3dxstat-esd-abs-3d-printing-filament/).
2. There are also [filament materials that are even more conductive than that](http://advancedmanufacturing.org/3d-printed-thermoplastics/).
3. Pretty much all rigid filaments can "take screws".  You can either have a hole that and let the screw self thread or tap the threads into the hole.  A better option is often to press a [threaded insert](https://www.matterhackers.com/articles/fasteners-for-3d-printing) into a hole.
4. The bigger question is why do you need this?  Are you trying to prevent ESD.  If so, why, are there ESD sensitive components?  If so, just make sure proper spacing is provided.  If you are trying to manage electrical emissions/susceptibility, there might be better solutions such as a coating.